# How to swap certain columns in .csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, csv

I have been searching for an answer, but I have found just messy solutions, I have a .csv file like this:

```
device_id,ip_address,serial_number
 Arq_Laboratorios_EdifB, 148.228.134.000,FOC1518Z1G8
 Arquitectura_Dir, 148.228.134.000,FOC1216U13V
 Arq.245, 148.228.134.000,FOC1352V3FE
 Barragan_3750, 148.228.134.000,FDO1129Z9ZJ
```

I only need to swap column number 3 and 1 so the file turns into this:

```
serial_number,device_id,ip_address
 FOC1518Z1G8,Arq_Laboratorios_EdifB, 148.228.134.000
 FOC1216U13V,Arquitectura_Dir, 148.228.134.000
 FOC1352V3FE,Arq.245, 148.228.134.000
 FDO1129Z9ZJ,Barragan_3750, 148.228.134.000
```

I'm pretty sure there should be an easy solution using sed or awk.

UPDATE:
using this awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{a=$1; $1=$3; $3=a}1' dispositivos.csv this is what I've got:

```
serial_number,ip_address,device_id
, 148.228.134.000, Arq_Laboratorios_EdifB
, 148.228.134.000, Arquitectura_Dir
, 148.228.134.000, Arq.245
, 148.228.134.000, Barragan_3750
```

I don't know what's happening with serial numbers.

Comment: your profile shows 16 questions tagged `awk`.. by now you should be able to at least show your attempt at solving, an easy one as you put it

Comment: What you want is NOT swapping col3 <-> col1. You need to be really clear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work ok:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$0=$3 FS $1 FS $2}1'
```

Comment: Updated.Try this one

Comment: It does the same, I think the way I added the serial numbers is affecting.
I'm using a for loop to find the serial number from "show version" and add it in a given line of the .csv file.  I think so, cause the first line does change.

Comment: I've used  "dos2unix dispositivos.csv" and then it worked.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -F, -ple '$_ = join ",", @F[2,0,1]'
```

Comment: @user218374 Even though this topic is 4 years old, you should always explain your answer.